# Database for querying a probabilistic automaton

Tags: database-design, database-recommendation, nosql, graph

I've got a probabilistic automaton of 4000 states, with 20 attributes attached to them, and 60 000 transitions between the states. I would like to, given a defined sequence of states, find all valid transitions between them. For example a user might define a sequence for three states, with only a certain amount of attributes defined, and I would like to return all valid transitions between these states.

Is there a database which could  be suitable for this kind of task?

Comment: Check [graph databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database). The most common at the moment is probably [Neo4J](https://neo4j.com).